# Snapshot and history graph of wave

Tags: waves

[[image]]

I don't understand why the wave is moving to the right, the x graph is showing downward movement and the right graph is showing upward with time. please explain better than the statement in the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider what is happening a little later in time, say $t=1\, \rm ms$.

The right hand graph shows you (red) that the particle at the origin $x=0$ now has a displacement of $35\,\rm mm$ from its equilibrium position.

[image].

Now consider that displacement of $35\,\rm mm$ at $x=0$ on the left hand graph and then complete the graph as shown in green.

You have a right travelling wave.